Brauer characters/ modular characters are not well defined
In chapter $15$ of Isaacs' "Character theory of finite groups", he defines a field $F$ of characteristic $p$, isomorphic to the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ of the prime field of characteristic $p$ and whose unit group is isomorphic to $U = \{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\text{ such that } \lambda^m = 1 \text{ for some } m\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ coprime with } p\}$. He does so by choosing a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ the algebraic intergers in $\mathbb{C}$ containing $p$ and letting $F = R/M$.
He then defines the Brauer / modular characters of a finite group in the usual way but on the next page, there is remark that i can't understand.

Some words of caution are appropriate here. Given a group $G$ and a function, $\varphi\colon \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of $p$-regular elements of $G$, it is not always meaningful to ask if $\varphi$ is a Brauer character unless the ideal $M\subseteq R$ is specified or some other additional information is given. Examples exist where $\varphi$ is a Brauer character with respect to some choice of $M$ and is not one when some other maximal ideal is chosen.

My problem is that, later on in this chapter, he proceeds to show that every irreducible character is obtained by restriction on $\mathcal{S}$ of an irreducible character over $\mathbb{C}$, but those irreducible characters exist outside of this construction, they do not depend at all on the choice of $M$.
Is this a question of $F$-representation that are not completely reducible and that characters of indecomposable modules are not obtained from characters over $\mathbb{C}$ ? Am I missing something else ? Could someone point to me an example of what he says in this remark ?

Not every irreducible Brauer character is obtained by restriction to $\mathcal S$ of an irreducible ordinary character. In general they decompose. This is the source of the problem.

An example is good: $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(32)$ has exactly five irreducible $2$-dimensional representations over a (large enough) field of characteristic $2$ up to isomorphism. Fix $x\in G$ a (diagonal) element of order $31$. Since each rep has two eigenvalues for the action of $x$, this means that exactly ten out of the 30 non-trivial $31$st roots of unity appear as eigenvalues of $x$. But all 30 roots of unity 'look the same', as in the Galois group acts transitively on them. So why are ten of them distinguished? The choice of maximal ideal.

Sorry, I'm not very familiar with those notions and the irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SL}_2(q)$ $($even on $\mathbb{C})$. I think i might be missing something, and that's maybe more of a field theoretic question, but i thought that since $F = R/M$ is always isomorphic to the algebraic closure $\overline{F_p}$ $($which is unique$)$, the eigenvalues of our irreducible representations on $F$ don't depend of the choice $M$ and that it's only when we try to see them as element of $\mathbb{C}$ that the choice of $M$ intervenes.

But to me, the argument you just made, that all $30$ roots of unity look the same, could also be applied to $F$ to indicates that there is a choice to be made for those eigenvalues in $F$ which confuses me a little bit since we have a natural action of their Galois group on the usual irreducible characters over $F$. Could you elaborate a bit more ?

Finite fields behave differently to $\mathbb{C}$. All 30 non-trivial 31st roots of unity look the same over $\mathbb{C}$ because $(x^{31}-1)/(x-1)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ and the Galois group acts transitively on the roots. For the Galois group of $\mathbb{F}_{32}$ (the splitting field of $x^{31}-1$) over $\mathbb{F}_2$, it has order $5$, so cannot act transitively on the roots. Indeed, $(x^{31}-1)/(x-1)$ splits as the product of six quintics over $\mathbb{F}_2$....

So there are six 'types' of non-trivial 31st roots of unity in characteristic $2$. Taking Brauer characters involves deciding which of these six types is assigned to $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm i/31}$. That's why they are not well-defined. There are three possible Brauer character tables for $\mathrm{SL}_2(32)$ in characteristic $2$, and no reordering of the rows will make them the same. If you allow to reorder the columns as well as the rows, then you can make them the same. The different types of primitive roots of unity over finite fields is what leads to the idea of Conway polynomials.
